# Show that $\| *\|_p$ represents a norm on $C([0, 1]).$

Tags: proof-verification, normed-spaces

A few weeks ago, I had to work on the following excercise:

> Assume,
>
> $$\|f\|_p := (\int_{0}^1 |f(x)|^p)^{1\over p}$$
>
> with $f \in C([0,1])$ and $p \in [1, \infty)$.
>
> Show that $\| *\|_p$ represents a norm on $C([0, 1]).$

Well, the first and second axioms are trivial. This leaves to prove the triangle inequality for norms, and back then, I simply wrote that the inequality follows directly from the Minkowski inequality. I received full points on the excercise, but in the tutorial, we showed the triangle inequality differently - with a much, much longer proof.

Now I wondered if I was indeed correct with simply refering to the Minkowski inequality or if I was just lucky that I got away with it.

Comment: The Minkowsky inequality is what you were trying to prove, so your argument was correct, and I guess your teacher proved this inequality.

Comment: No, we already proved it in the lecture, so there was no need to do it.

Comment: Or are you talking about the Minkowski inequality for integrals? Because we proved the inequality only vectors, hence I wondered why my answer was marked as correct.

Comment: If you approximate the integrals by Riemann sums you see Minkowski for integrals (of continuous functions on $[0,1]$) follows from Minkowski for vectors.